# Trouble installing Oracle Developer Studio

Tags: package-management, solaris

ALL,

```
root@solaris:~# df -k
Filesystem           1024-blocks        Used   Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/s11.3qa_example_backup
                       511967232     5085980   495960478     2%    /
/devices                       0           0           0     0%    /devices
/dev                           0           0           0     0%    /dev
ctfs                           0           0           0     0%    /system/contract
proc                           0           0           0     0%    /proc
mnttab                         0           0           0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                      996508        1668      994840     1%    /system/volatile
objfs                          0           0           0     0%    /system/object
sharefs                        0           0           0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap2.so.1
                       501046458     5085980   495960478     2%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                             0           0           0     0%    /dev/fd
rpool/ROOT/s11.3qa_example_backup/var
                       511967232      294082   495960478     1%    /var
swap                     1125976      131136      994840    12%    /tmp
rpool/VARSHARE         511967232          52   495960478     1%    /var/share
rpool/export           511967232          32   495960478     1%    /export
rpool/export/home      511967232          32   495960478     1%    /export/home
rpool/export/home/igor
                       511967232      201698   495960478     1%    /export/home/igor
rpool                  511967232        4978   495960478     1%    /rpool
rpool/VARSHARE/zones   511967232          31   495960478     1%    /system/zones
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg     511967232          32   495960478     1%    /var/share/pkg
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg/repositories
                       511967232          31   495960478     1%    /var/share/pkg/repositories
/dev/dsk/c3t1d0s2          55748       55748           0   100%    /media/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.38_106717
/export/home/igor      496162176      201698   495960478     1%    /home/igor
root@solaris:~# zfs list -r rpool
NAME                                    USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool                                  15.3G   473G  4.86M  /rpool
rpool/ROOT                             13.0G   473G    31K  legacy
rpool/ROOT/s11.3qa_example_backup      87.9M   473G  4.85G  /
rpool/ROOT/s11.3qa_example_backup/var  41.9M   473G   287M  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris                      106M   473G  3.21G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-1                   12.9M   473G  3.26G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-1/var               5.50M   473G   365M  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris-2                   12.7G   473G  6.71G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-2-backup-1          52.9M   473G  4.83G  /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-2-backup-1/var         1K   473G  1.38G  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris-2/var               2.78G   473G   767M  /var
rpool/ROOT/solaris/var                 75.9M   473G   271M  /var
rpool/VARSHARE                          146K   473G  52.5K  /var/share
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg                       63K   473G    32K  /var/share/pkg
rpool/VARSHARE/pkg/repositories          31K   473G    31K  /var/share/pkg/repositories
rpool/VARSHARE/zones                     31K   473G    31K  /system/zones
rpool/dump                             1.03G   473G  1.00G  -
rpool/export                            200M   473G    32K  /export
rpool/export/home                       200M   473G    32K  /export/home
rpool/export/home/igor                  200M   473G   200M  /export/home/igor
rpool/swap                             1.03G   473G  1.00G  -
```

According to [requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E77782_01/html/E77783/gljrn.html) I need 2G temporary disk space and 1G for the installed product. I also need 8G swap space.

Now IIUC, I have 400G of swap space, but I think I'm a little off on the temporary space. Now the requirement says I need 4G of RAM which I will just increase on the VM settings.

So can someone help me with the hard drive space? How do I make the install work on this VM?

Thank you.

P.S.: Apparently I was wrong and I do have just 1G of the swap space:

```
igor@solaris:~$ swap -lh
swapfile             dev    swaplo   blocks     free
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap 195,1        4K     1.0G     1.0G
```

So, now there are 2 questions:

1. How to increase the swap space to satisfy the requirements?
2. How to increase the temp space to satisfy the requirements?

TIA!

Comment: That looks like you have 1G of swap space, and 473G available on the ZFS pool holding your swap space.  Try running `swap -lh` to confirm.

Comment: @alanc, but then I need to increase the swap and the temporary space, right? Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Also, don't fixate too much on the requirements. If you're touching swap at all during packaging operations, you're probably hosed, anyway, and you should allocate more RAM to your VM. Does `pkg` (assuming Solaris 11) succeed or fail, and if it fails, what errors do you see?